Join multi-point layer to line layer
I am wanting to find the height of a land feature by taking elevation data from points every 10cm, then joining those attributes to a line layer (finding the height of each line by subtracting the minimum elevation from the max).
I have managed to get the lines and sampled points with elevation attributes. I want to group the points to their respective line to find the overall height on the line. I have tried the 'Join attributes by location' function, but as I'm joining elevation data from multiple points to single lines, I'm not sure this would work as I would need additional lines in the line layers attribute table to cover all of the points associated with each line.
Can anyone assist? Is there an easier way to find the elevation data of individual lines?

These are my lines and point layers that I currently have.

I'm essentially conducting a height audit. I want to find the height of each line and to produce a result similar to above.

Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which explains how our Focused question/Best answer model operates. Please [Edit] the Question to specify the GIS software in use, and the exact release you are using. You might consider changing the Question to state the starting point, and the goal rather than the rather convoluted solution involving elevation sampling of what is probably a unmanageably large number of points.

More details please on what you're trying to do.

Add a tag for the software you are using. So for each green line you want to find the intersecting point with the highest elevation, and the point with the lowest, and add the difference between them as an attribute to each line?

Your question remains unclear. Please revise it if you want to get help.
